# I can define let as a variable, but it should give syntax error as let is a keyword. On the other hand defining const as a variable gives error

Tags: javascript, variables

I was playing around with JavaScript variable declaration syntax. `var`, `let`, and `const` are keywords to declare variables. I tried declaring a variable name `let`, which is a keyword, and it was defined successfully. On the other hand, I tried defining `const` as a variable and it gave syntax error, that is perfectly fine.

I want to know why it didn't gave error for defining `let` as a variable

*Browser Info:*

Chrome 84.0.4147.105,
Firefox 79.0,
Firefox Dev Edition 80.0b7

[image]

Comment: `const` has been reserved for a long  time.

Comment: I don't think the question is "why didn't `const` work" but "why did `let` work"

Comment: Might also be informative to know what browser & version the user tried this in.

Comment: @Taplar, added browser information.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When javascript was created, a large list of keywords was reserved for future use. This included things which are used now, like `const` and `class`, as well as some which are still unused (for example, `enum`).
From the very beginning, you could never use those words as identifiers

`let` wasn't on that list, and is not a "real" keyword.
So to maintain backwards compatibility with code that was written before the `let` "keyword" was added, it needs to be usable as a variable name

Comment: see [this page](https://mathiasbynens.be/notes/javascript-identifiers#reserved-words) for a further explanation

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Lexical_grammar  related MDN article (MDN only because for some reason the ecmascript site has a security thing for me at work)

Comment: Above MDN document was really helpful. I wrote a summary regarding this observation. https://dev.to/dejunaidam/is-let-not-a-reserved-keyword-in-javascript-56bh